# 404 with axis2 WebService on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have developed a simple web service with axis2 and eclipse IDE. Currently I am running it on tomcat (7.x) in embedded mode in Eclipse and it works fine. However, when I create a WAR file and put it on webapps directory and then startup tomcat I get this warning:

```
[WARN] Web application uses org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet; pl
ease update web.xml to use org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet instead
```

I use SoapUI for testing and get "empty" response with headers:

```
Date    Tue, 12 Nov 2013 12:07:46 GMT
Content-Length  0
status  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: Did you try to update web.xml as suggested in the logs ?

Comment: Yes. It makes WARN disappear, however I get ~class not found exception. It stops working in Eclipse, so I guess its wrong approach.

Comment: Did you check in the tomcat manager whether the app was actually deployed ?

Comment: I am not able. Because when I try to open http://localhost:8090/manager/html/ via webbrowser I get blank page (no source). 404 I guess.